# Git ignore is not ignoring the netbeans private files

Tags: git, netbeans, gitignore

When ever I do git status, the netbeans private.xml is making trouble, I tried adding that in git ignore several ways. but the gitignore simply does not ignore it.

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

   modified:   .gitignore
   modified:   nbproject/private/private.xml
...
```

My git ignore file is

```
node_modules/
dist/
*.log
nbproject/private/*    
*.bak
*.orig
*~
*.log
*private.xml
```

Tried both 
nbproject/private/*
and 
*private.xml
in the same file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A file which is already tracked would not be ignored: you need to remove from the index first.

```
git rm --cached private.xml 
git add -u .
git commit -m "Record deletion of private.xml from the index"
```

(the `--cached` option make sure the file remains on the disk)

Then you can add it in the .gitignore (no need for '*')

```
private.xml
```

Note: whenever an file is or is not ignored, you can check out which `.gitignore` rule applies with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- private.xml
```

Answer (score 5):

Your file is already **added** to the git repo.
Once file is added (not untracked) adding it to .gitignore will not ignore it since its already in the repo so you have to **remove** it from the repository, commit the deletion of the file and then it will be ignored.

See [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475983/1755598) code above on how to do it.

> The important thing to understand is that once the file is already commited, adding it to git ignore will not ignore it.